# SQL Query Merge 2 Columns Into 1 Column By Eliminating Selected Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data like this:

[image]

How to merge the columns into one column without 110? Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `case`.  For your data, this seems to work:

```
select name,
       (case when credit_code = 110 then debit_code else credit_code end)
from t;
```

If both could be `110`, then you would want:

```
select name,
       (case when credit_code <> 110 then credit_code
             when debit_code <> 110 then debit_code
        end) as code
from t;
```

Comment: Sorry but when I added a data without 110 in both columns, the query still gets all of the data whether it contains 110 or not. Solutions?

Comment: @ryanderon . . . I don't understand your comment.  This answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: here is my new question, please help, thanks @Gordon Linoff https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60292112/sql-query-merge-2-columns-into-1-column-by-eliminating-value