# SQL Query Merge 2 Columns Into 1 Column By Eliminating Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data like this

[image: my data]

I have tried to merge the columns into one column without 110, but my output is like this:

[image]

> PS: Selling 7 and Selling 8 is not contains 110, I didn't want to show it

my query:

```
select name,
       (case when credit_code <> 110 then credit_code
             when debit_code <> 110 then debit_code
        end) as code from t;
```

My expected output is like this:

[image: expected output]

How to query like my expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want rows that have a 110 in one of the columns, use a `where` clause:

```
select name,
       (case when credit_code <> 110 then credit_code
             when debit_code <> 110 then debit_code
        end) as code
from t
where 110 in (credit_code, debit_code);
```